# How to enqueue additional scripts and styles after loading another post into the DOM?

Tags: actions, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

If have a `post_showcase` shortcode that takes in post_ids as parameters. The shortcode generates buttons that when click will load the given post into a modal. However, the shortcodes within the subpost loaded into the modal will sometimes have their own javascript and css that need to be enqueued. However despite the `wp_enqueue_script` function getting called, nothing happens.

Is there a way to enqueue additional scripts after the page has already loaded?

Comment: Do you know in advanced which scripts and styles are required?

Comment: you could try enqueueing them in the footer or include the javascript inline along with the output from the shortcode. Once a shortcode has been fired, by that stage the enqueue for the header has already run, so your only option is to use the `wp_footer` hook, enqueue in the footer, or inline. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61268290/wordpress-wp-enqueue-script-and-jquery-in-footer